# Log4j2 - nothing logged in file

Tags: java, websphere, log4j2

I am using log4j2 on a webapp deployed on Websphere 8.5.5. The application logs in the log file on one of the websphere instances while on the other instance nothing is logged in the log file. The log file is created at the application start but it remains empty. Here is my log4j2.xml

```
<Configuration name="productapp">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="filename">c:/logs/productapp.log</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Filter type="ThresholdFilter" level="trace" />

    <Appenders>     
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m MDC%X%n"/>
        </Console>      
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="${filename}" filePattern="c:/logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>      
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="au.com.test.productdata" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />            
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="au.com.test.productdata" level="debug"    additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile" />
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.glassfish.jersey" level="WARN"    additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

There are no errors in SystemOut logs. What could be going wrong?

Comment: On the other instance websphere bootstrap classloader was adding logback jar files. Because of that logging was being handled by logback. Removing the logback jar files from the bootrstrap classloader fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try `fileName="${sys:filename}"`.

Comment: After changing to fileName="${sys:filename}" it is not creating the log file. Earlier the log file was created but nothing was written to it.

Comment: You can try configuring with `<Configuration status="TRACE" name="productapp">` to see if the log4j2 debug info provides a clue. UPDATE - Looks like Ralph is suggesting the same... :-) Hi Ralph!

Answer (score 0):

May not be quite the same problem you are having, but I recently ran into the same symptoms (log file created but nothing written to it).  In my case everything was getting written to stdout and I couldn't do anything to change that.

I believe mine was caused by a bug in log4j2 where I did **not** have a log4j2.xml file in my classpath but instead defined it through the `log4j.configurationFile` external file only.  Adding a bogus log4j2.xml in my classpath fixed the issue for me.  However, this may not work for you since it sounds like you have two instances of the same webapp where one works and one doesn't, but I thought I'd document it here for those that run into the same issue.

I also created a ticket [with log4j2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-973) with a lengthier description of the problem I observed.